# display alert when form is submitted

Tags: php, javascript

I need to display the alert saying thanx your msg is received but this doesnot works so please hel me out how to do.Is there coding error or what i coudnt get to it.i would pe pleased if someone helps me out.thankyou

```
 <h4>Send Your Feedback Here.<p>

      <form name ="register" action="contact.php" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">

          Name<br>
          <input type="text" name="name" size="30">
        </p>
        <p>
        Email<br>
        <input type="text" name="email" size="30"></p><p>
         Message<br>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
        <p>

        </p>          
        <p>
        Security Check<br>

            Sum of <?php $a = rand(0,9);
                        $b = rand(0,9); 
                        echo $a . "+" . $b ; 
                        $result = $a + $b ;
                        ?>  =       
            <input type="text" name="ver"  /><input type="hidden" name="rval" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" />
          <button type="button" onClick="validate()">Send</button>
        </p>
      </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
    {
        var x = document.register.ver.value;
        var y = document.register.rval.value;
        var nameCheck = document.register.name.value, 
        emailCheck = document.register.email.value, 
        msgCheck = document.register.message.value;

    var msg ="";
    if(x!=y)
    {
    msg+= "Sorry!! Captcha Mismached."+"\n";
    }
    if(nameCheck=="")
    {
        msg+= "Dont you have a name????"+"\n";
    }
    if(emailCheck=="")
    {
        msg+= "Enter email... how am I supposed to contact you"+"\n";
    }
    if(msgCheck="")
    {
        msg+= "Dont you have any messages for me??"+"\n";
    }   

    if(msg!="")
    {
    alert(msg);
    }

    else
    {
            <?php
//Get message data.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$ver = $_POST['ver'];  
$rval = $_POST['rval'];

if($ver==$rval)
{
//Email it.
mail(
  'example@example.com',  //Where to send
"Contact form - $name", //Email subject
  $message,               //Message body
  $email                    //email address  
);
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Thank you form is submitted');</script>";
    }
else
{
     echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Wrong captcha');</script>";
}

?>

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix JavaScript and PHP like that. The PHP will be parsed on the served before the page is served up to the user. Including it inside of your JavaScript `else` block will have no effect, since the code will be run when the page is generated anyway.

You should look into the use of [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function thevalidate()
    {
        var x = document.register.ver.value;
        var y = document.register.rval.value;
        var nameCheck = document.register.name.value, 
        emailCheck = document.register.email.value, 
        msgCheck = document.register.message.value;

        var msg ="";
        if(x!=y) {
            msg+= "Sorry!! Captcha Mismached."+"\n";
        }

        if(nameCheck=="") {
            msg+= "Dont you have a name????"+"\n";
        }
        if(emailCheck=="") {
            msg+= "Enter email... how am I supposed to contact you"+"\n";
        }
        if(msgCheck="") {
            msg+= "Dont you have any messages for me??"+"\n";
        }   

        if(msg!="") {
            alert(msg);
        } else {


            <?php
            //You need  to process data here..
            ?>


        }
}

</script>
 <h4>Send Your Feedback Here.<p>

      <form name ="register" action="php/process.php" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">

          Name<br>
          <input type="text" name="name" size="30">
        </p>
        <p>
        Email<br>
        <input type="text" name="email" size="30"></p><p>
         Message<br>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
        <p>

        </p>          
        <p>
        Security Check<br>

            Sum of <?php $a = rand(0,9);
                        $b = rand(0,9); 
                        echo $a . "+" . $b ; 
                        $result = $a + $b ;
                        ?>  =       
            <input type="text" name="ver"  /><input type="hidden" name="rval" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" />
          <button type="button" onClick="thevalidate()">Send</button>
        </p>
      </form>
```